# Best way to clear a Model in ASP MVC Create Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In other questions I have read many things about the Create action on a Controller, where the best practice is to perform an RedirectToAction to the GET method, but what if I want to show a succesfully saved message and clear the model or a submit a **submit and create new** input type. For example here is my code, is there a better standard compliant way of clearing the create model?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RegisterUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       /* perform create action validation and operation in service and repository layers */
       var service = new UserManagementService();
       var registerUser = service.RegisterUser(model);

       if(registerUser == ServiceStatus.Successful)
       {
          //Here I set the "Correctly created" message to the model
          model.ServiceResponse = registerUser;
          //Here I "clear" my model
          ModelState.Clear();
          model = new RegisterUserViewModel();
          //What is the most useful suggestion is this, but here I can´t pass model data
          //return RedirectToAction("Create");
      }
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You can use `TempData` for your message, then retrieve it in the GET method when you redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RegisterUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       /* perform create action validation and operation in service and repository layers */
       var service = new UserManagementService();
       var registerUser = service.RegisterUser(model);

       if(registerUser == ServiceStatus.Successful)
       {

            //set succesfully saved message
            TempData["Message"] = "Success Message";
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
      }
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: what if I want to send and object? TempData can send objects?

Comment: yes, you can pass/send objects in tempdata  and you can also pass object as parameter to RedirectToAction() method. refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx